# How to fit Mission Banner

Tags: ingress

I will do a Mission Banner that is 2x6, but my missions are not "squared"

Right now looks like this:

[image]

So in future, if I do more missions and don't want to be the banners messed up,
What do I have to do?

PS: Someone told me to do the banner, and then repeat the necessary missions I have since the banners move right. Or is better to do random missiones until fill the line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Missions fill in from the top-left corner, with the most recent first.
If you do a banner of 12 missions, they will line up properly, but your last line of mission badges won't fill a full line (since they don't at the moment either).

Basically, your badge list will look the same, but with the banner above it, similar to this:

[image: banner mission alignment]

If it bothers you that the end of your list isn't aligned properly, then you can do more missions before you start the banner.

Also, as mentioned by udondan, if you redo a mission then that moves it to the start of your list. So if you did the banner missions, then redo 4 of the missions you'd already done (which would move them ahead of your banner), then 2 new missions, then everything would be aligned perfectly: your banner would be lined up, and your bottom row would be full.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to re-order mission badges is to redo a mission. The last mission you did always is at the top left. So if you do a big banner, mosaic or whatever you call in, you have to complete the missions in the correct order.

You can redo missions any time and this will put the badge on the top left again.